# vim plugins errors

Tags: vim

I've recently installed some plugins for vim, like vimtex, using vumble.

But opening a `.tex` file with vim, returns forward errors:

```
vimtex warning: Zathura is not executable!
- vimtex viewer will not work!

vimtex warning: Can't use callbacks without +clientserver
```

My zathura implementation in my `.vimrc` is set like this:

```
let g:latex_view_general_viewer = 'zathura'

let g:vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
```

I've researched those things, but I've found nothing that help me.

This is the first time I'm configuring vim things, so if I've missed obvious things, let me know.

EDIT:
got zathura to work, seemed i needed to install this feature, not only include the plugin.

Comment: So do you have the package `zathura` installed?

Comment: by now ive found that was indeed the problem, and ive installed the zatura package, now only the clientserver error remains.

Comment: So please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/920882/edit).

Comment: so is this question solved, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: still looking how to configure the clientserver problem

Comment: You need to update your question with details relating to that then, please

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean using 'vundle' not vumble.

For the +clientserver error check what functionality you have compiled in your version of vim by running:

```
vim --version
```

Check if you have -clientserver or +clientserver. If it's the former, you'll need to replace your vim installation with a version that has clientserver support, or compile it yourself.